# Bootstrap tab does not showing/updating content when navigating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap tab does not show/update content when navigating. Any idea how to fix this?

This is my code:

```
<div class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="">
      <div class="modal-header">

        <h4 class="modal-title">Personalise your gift</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div>

        <!-- Nav tabs -->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
          <li role="presentation" ><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
        </ul>

        <!-- Tab panes -->
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">home</div>
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">profile</div>
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">messages</div>
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">settings</div>
        </div>

      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

This is literally a bootstrap tab under modal. Fancybox isn't working either.

Comment: Can you share some of your code?

Comment: We're not prophet. We can't diagnose your issue unless you provide codes.

Comment: Fancybox isn't working hinted that there is at least 1 JS error. Maybe you can look into Developer Console for error and fix that first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED:**

Let me know if this is what you're looking for:

**A working example:**

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wKwvZN

**Full Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="myModalName" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Personalise your gift</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container">
                    <h2>Dynamic Tabs</h2>
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
                        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
                        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                            <h3>HOME</h3>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
                            <h3>Menu 1</h3>
                            <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
                            <h3>Menu 2</h3>
                            <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
                            <h3>Menu 3</h3>
                            <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

Background text here...

blah blah blah...

<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#myModalName').modal({
            show: true
        })
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Please don't forget to click "accept answer" if this answers your question.  Thanks :)

Comment: thanks for the code man, but you test it bootstrap tab working properly under modal?

Comment: dude, sorry im newbie here, but can you do a popup and then trying to work with tabs? pls thank you!

Comment: we can do. no problem. but, show your code, where you are calling modal pop up

Comment: @PakaluPapito Do you want a popup first, and then the tabs inside of that popup?

Comment: @PakaluPapito I put new code up in my question above.  It should give you a popup modal with working tabs inside of it.  Please click "accept as answer" if this answers your question :) thanks!